# Appium inspector error and could not find a device to launch error

Tags: java, ios, automation, appium, appium-ios

```
 import java.io.File;
 //import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 //import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
 import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
 import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;
 import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;


    public class testone{

    public static IOSDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

        File appDir = new File ("//Users//gangaiahl//Appium//jars//CarsGuideApp//Payload");
        File app = new File (appDir,"Car.app");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Car_iPhone_6");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.2.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("device", "iPhone 6");

        //capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPad 2");
        //capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.4");
        //capabilities.setCapability("device", "iPad");

        capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("u_did",  "840384833537f40d011032eaaf20a53705a451ce");
         //capabilities.setCapability("u_did", "5446DE10-D8D1-4346-B8C7-E4C16053FE3A");
//840384833537f40d011032eaaf20a53705a451ce
        capabilities.setCapability("bundle_id", "au.dev.com.onewaytraffic.carsguide");
```

driver = new IOSDriver (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);

}

```
@Test
public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    // fail("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

[image][image]

Please see the attached screenshot and error from a screenshot . Can anyone help me?
I am using Appium on Mac 10.10.5 version &  automating iOS Mobile App

Comment: Please elaborate what have you tried and what configurations you saved. Adding just a image in question does not make any sense.. There are many reasons for which inspector can not open.
         1. the device you want to inspect is not opened with this appium        session.

Comment: Please see the attached screen for the settings and the capabilities been defined in the script

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the device you will work with(real ios device or ios simulator)

Comment: is my configuration wrong, or wat is the correct one or how to configure them?

Comment: I mean you have to check your configuration, is the version you are using for ios simulator exists ? and all that, and you have to launch the inspector only after the launch of simulator may be you click into inspector beore the device is loaded !